# JsHint warning: A regular expression literal can be confused with '/='

Tags: javascript, jshint

I have this line in my Javascript code:

```
var regex = /===Hello===\n/;
```

JsHint gives me a warning in this line:

```
A regular expression literal can be confused with '/='`
```

...but I don't know what's wrong with this regular expression? How can I avoid this warning?

Comment: Why do you use a regular expression here at all?

Comment: *g* you are right, the example wasn't good. My real code has a much bigger regexp that really has to be a regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `/=` could be interpreted as a division and assignment, rather than the start of a regular expression literal.

You can avoid the warning by using the [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) instead:

```
var regex = new RegExp("===Hello===\n");
```

There doesn't appear to be [any option](http://www.jshint.com/docs/) you can set to tell JSHint (or JSLint for that matter) to ignore `/=`, so your choice is either to work around it or ignore the warning.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I didn't think about divisions. I will use your RegExp solution.

Comment: I've added a bit more info on this error to [the article](http://jslinterrors.com/a-regular-expression-literal-can-be-confused-with/) at http://jslinterrors.com.